# View Array Type in dnSpy

Tags: binary-analysis, .net

I'm debugging a .NET application and see a declaration of a local array:

```
$ArrayType$$$BY05PAD $ArrayType$$$BY05PAD;
```

I break on an instruction that uses data inside that (char*) array:

```
num9 = <Module>.strtoul(*(ref $ArrayType$$$BY05PAD + 4), null, 10);
```

Before the call to strtoul, I want to show in a hex editor the contents of *(ref $ArrayType$$$BY05PAD + 4), but this is not a valid expression in the watch window and it doesn't appear as a local variable. How can I inspect raw field memory?

Comment: what happens if you, in `Locals` window, right click on this array and select `Show in Memory window` -> `Memory 1`?

Comment: Hi Paweł, unfortunately the array does not appear at all in the Locals window.

Comment: is it possible that you put this binary somewhere for me to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are identified as `raw locals`. You can enable their visibility by going to `Options` in `Debug` menu.

[image]

After that you will be able to see those elements in the locals window.

[image]

And from there you can right click on it and select `Show in Memory Window` -> `Memory 1`

[image]

and analyze the data:

[image]

But that's not the end of our work. Those are just the pointers so our array contains such addresses (little-endian):

```
[0x610245D4,0x610245D7,0x610245DA,0x610245DD,0x610245E0]
```

So if your example tries to access offset `+4` it will get the second address and if we navigate there in the `Memory window` we will see the strings there that will be passed to `strtoul` method

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, this is exactly what I was looking for!